# How do I remove the last comma of SQL array?

Tags: php, sql

How do I remove the last comma on this array? I'm using SQL in this code.

```
<?php
$no=1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>                            
{lat: <?php echo $row['lat'] ?>, 
lng: <?php echo $row['lng'] ?>},
<?php
}
?>
```

I expect the output to be:

```
{lat: -7.0476101, lng: 112.7323577}, {lat: -7.0319093, lng: 112.7614287}, {lat: -7.0433001, lng: 112.7606889}, {lat: -7.0459718, lng: 112.7583679} //last comma doesnt exist
```

But the result is:

```
{lat: -7.0476101, lng: 112.7323577}, {lat: -7.0319093, lng: 112.7614287}, {lat: -7.0433001, lng: 112.7606889}, {lat: -7.0459718, lng: 112.7583679}, //last comma exists
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't an SQL thing, you're outputing that comma yourself in your php.

Comment: Are you intending this to be json encoded, or are you just wanting to display it this way?

Comment: Yes, I just want to make sure that the data comes from SQL. Is it possible to turns the data to array, so I can use implode in this case? @Ben

Comment: @TimMorton both are really helpful

Comment: yes, array and implode is the way to go.

Comment: Instead of writing a bad JSON encoder you should just use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: It's also possible to fetch the entire result as an array in one fell swoop using `fetchall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to see the output formatted this way, the easiest way is to store the results as an array, and use `join` or `implode` to put it together as a string:

```
<?php

$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $result[] = sprintf("{lat:%s, lng:%s}",
              $row['lat'],
              $row['lng']
              );
}

echo join(', ',$result);
// or,
?>

<!-- if you're sticking this in a web page... ->
<?= join(', ',$result) ?>
```

using `json_encode` is even easier:

```
<?php
$no=1;
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $result[] = array($row['lat'] => $row['lng']);
}

print json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: I don't have access to a php console right now, so I'm not sure if the curly braces will cause a problem in the `sprintf`

Answer (score 0):

That issue in your `php` application not `MYSQL` so

**Try this one**

```
<?php
$no=1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>                            
<?php
}
?>
lat: <?php echo $row['lat'];?> 
lng: <?php echo $row['lng'];?>

<?php
}
?>
```

### or Try this way from your code

```
<?php
$no=1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>                            
{lat: <?php echo $row['lat'] ?>, 
lng: <?php echo $row['lng'] ?>},
<?php
}
?>
$tempRow =rtrim($row,',');

<?php
echo $tempRow; 
?>
```

rtrim($row,',') function removes your last ' , '

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to use:

```
$json = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

To help you see what is happening, start with:

```
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

that will show you what is returned from **fetchAll**

You want to see an array of object, or an array of associative arrays

Next use:

```
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

this will show you exactly what is produced

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>                            
{lat: <?php echo $row['lat'] ?>, 
<?php if( $count == $rows ) { ?>
   lng: <?php echo $row['lng'] ?>}
 <?php }else{ ?>
lng: <?php echo $row['lng'] ?>},
<?php } ?>

<?php
}
?>
```